# Why binding rvalue to a const type makes it an lvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, std-pair

This question may not have the best title but here is the code that will explain what I am trying to ask.

This code runs and prints "lvalue" but If I remove `const` from MyPair's first type, it gives me the expected output, which is "rvalue". I would like to know what role `const` plays here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>


using MyPair = std::pair<const std::string, int>;


void func(std::string&& str)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}

void func(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void func_forward(T&& p)
{
    func(std::forward<T>(p).first);
}

void test(MyPair&& p)
{
    func_forward(std::move(p));
}

int main()
{
    test({"hello", 3});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `first` is `const`-qualified, but `func`'s parameter is not, so that overload can't be viable, irregardless of value categories. So then there is only the other `func` overload which has a `const`-qualified parameter. Nothing is being turned into a lvalue there. A `const` lvalue reference can bind to a rvalue.

Comment: Once you give something a name it becomes a lvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is being turned into a lvalue.

`std::forward<T>(p).first` is in your example's instantiation is a rvalue (specifically xvalue) regardless of the `const`. However, it's *type* will be `const std::string` or `std::string` depending on the choice of `const` in the `MyPair` type.

The problem is that your method of differentiating lvalues from rvalues with `func` is incorrect, because the first overload of `func`'s parameter is not `const`-qualified and so will only accept rvalues of non-`const` `std::string` type.

Your second `func` overload on the other hand can accept any value category and `const`-qualification because a `const` lvalue reference is allowed to bind to lvalues as well as rvalues. So it will be chosen if `first` is `const` qualified, regardless of value category as the the only viable overload.

To fix your detection method use `const std::string&&` instead of `std::string&&` as parameter type in the first `func` overload.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the addition of `const` to the first member of the pair means that you're passing an xvalue of type `const std::string` to `func`, and an rvalue reference `std::string&&` cannot bind to that, because it would discard the `const` qualifier.

Out of the two overloads, with `const` on the first member:

- `func(std::string&&)` cannot be called
- `func(const std::string&)` can be called, because `const std::string&` can bind to xvalues as well

Once you remove the `const` from the first member of the pair:

- `func(std::string&&)` is a better match for an xvalue of type `std::string`, because it requires no qualification conversions
- `func(const std::string&)` requires a qualification conversion (to add `const`), so it loses in overload resolution

Note that `std::forward<T>(p).first` does not turn into an lvalue, regardless whether `first` is `const` or not. This expression is always going to be an xvalue, assuming that `p` is an rvalue reference.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I can just green check one answer. I really appreciate it. :)